# localhost APIs & React-Native Expo APP & Accessing API In React-Native App

Tags: node.js, react-native, localhost

I am developing an App using React-Native (Expo) and my backend APIs are in node js Express.
I want access to APIs (localhost) in my React-Native App and both are on a single computer.

I have a limited internet connection during development, but I have a wireless router that most of the time without an internet connection.

What are your suggestions?
How can I access my APIs?
Expo App on my Android phone is not opening without an internet connection.
Is there any way?

It will be your kindness to suggest some solution.